# Sequence without average density

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

How to (if it's possible) build infinite binary sequence in that `0`-elements density will not converge to any value?
For example, in $30\%_{one}\over70\%_{zero}$ **random** sequence (average) density (of `0`-elements) converges to 70%,
or in `11010010001000010000010000001000...` (I don't know the formula) density will be 100% (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you pointing out my mistake, or there was no negative tone in your comment?

Comment: What mistake are you talking about? Isn't it clear that I wrote about typesetting, not about the *contents* of your post?

Comment: Ok, so I didn't recognized the tone in your comment, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$01001100001111000000001111111100000000000000001111111111111111\dots$$

Comment: There will be 50/50 density, non? (For every block of zeros existing similar block of ones.) Or that doesn't works with infinite seqs?

Comment: @Gordem try to show it rigorously with the limit. I suppose it should not exist.

Comment: If you stop after $2$, or $6$, or $14$, or $30$, and so on, terms, yes, the limit will be $1/2$. But that's not how densities work. If you stop after $1$, or $4$, or $10$, or $22$, and so on, the density will be much higher.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I don't know lims at all, but I'll try to understand.

Comment: If you don't know limits, you don't have any chance of understanding densities. Densities are *defined* as limits.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1422533)

Comment: @Mohsen, it certainly is an answer, it just requires OP to think about it a bit. It's much better than doing all the work for OP, to let OP reason some things out on his/her own.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I totally agree that giving hints is much better than doing all the work, especially in this case that the OP has shown almost no effort. As the OP is new to MSE, people should've helped him/her to improve the post and include his/her own attempts. Also, this post is very good as a comment.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Nevertheless, MSE is a place for searching answers to questions. For someone with the same questions in the future, searching and finding an answer with enough explanation is important. A question with an accepted answer is saved for those situations in the future, so that the question won't be asked again, and if it is asked, marked as duplicate of the previous one. So in addition to helping the OP to come up with the answer by himself/herself, it's important that the answers be complete and contain enough explanation. That's why this had better to be a comment than an answer.

Comment: "For someone with the same questions in the future, searching and finding an answer with enough explanation is important." @Mohsen, for someone with the same question in the future, finding an answer that leaves her with some work to do is even more important. It's good enough for OP, and it's good enough for future searchers.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Amounts of zeros and ones are clearly the same, but the density of seq above _doesn't_ converge with lims - if to draw a one-by-one diagram of one's part, it "jumps" to 1/2 and smoothly falls to 1/3 - diagram becomes a "saw" with longer and longer "jags".

Comment: Exactly! Good work, Gordem.